# Resizing With Photoshop Elements

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, adobe-photoshop-elements

Usually, when I crop an image in **Photoshop**, I can drag around the area and just crop. 
But when I try this in **Photoshop Elements**, however, the image is always resized.

**Is there a way I can just crop and not scale so it's insanely small?**

Comment: First thought that comes to mind, is that maybe you have width or height set in your crop tool settings.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if your `fixed crop` `width` and `height` dimensions are set in the options bar.

If they are, then remove them, and it should be good.